# Marquee analogue or widget in qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, marquee, qooxdoo

Did't find something like running string (marquee) in `qooxdoo`. Running string is needed for `qx.ui.basic.Label` for cases when string is to long and widget length is not enough. I would write my own wrapper for html **marquee** tag by myself but it is deprecated component. I know it could be done via CSS. Any code or easy solution suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

I find marquees annoying and distracting, so an alternative that I prefer to use is a tooltip that contains the complete text, so that mouseover will reveal it:

```
let doc = this.getRoot();
let text = "This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system. This is only a test.";
let label = new qx.ui.basic.Label(text);
label.set(
  {
    width       : 100,
    toolTipText : text
  });

doc.add(
  label,
  {
    left : 100,
    top  : 50
  });
```

In the very distant past, we had a demo of a marquee, but I'm pretty sure it was implemented with a JavaScript timer. For the short term, while the `<marquee>` tag is still working in all standard browsers, you could simply make use of it like this:

```
let doc = this.getRoot();
let text = "This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system. This is only a test.";
let label = new qx.ui.basic.Label(`<marquee>${text}</marquee>`);
label.set(
  {
    width       : 100,
    rich        : true,
    toolTipText : text
  });

doc.add(
  label,
  {
    left : 100,
    top  : 50
  });
```

I'd be careful that `text` is sanitized, when using `rich`.
You're right, though, that with it deprecrated, you should be working towards a standards-compliant implementation.

Finally, you can implement a marquee style sheet as described at https://www.w3schools.in/css3/css-marquee or many other places, by adding a style sheet for it (look at the source code for `qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract` in method `_createStyleSheet() for an example of creating a style sheet`), and then manipulating the attributes of your label's `label.getContentElement().getDomElement()`.